# does eosjs only support eosio and eosio.token contract?

Tags: javascript

I suppose lookupAsync and lookup should remove 'contract' param.
For example, my contract name is 'adv', if I use 'adv' as contract name, it will post a wrong argument to get_currency_stats like this:

curl http://172.17.0.2:8888/v1/chain/get_currency_stats -X POST -d '{"code":"adv","symbol":"ADV"}'

but in fact, the 'code' field must be eosio.token in most case.

Also 'lookup' function has same issue.

Once I remove contract param and set local var 'contract' to eosio.token, my webapp works fine, at least in this stage.

but the ’@‘ is referenced many times in eosjs, I'm not sure about such change is OK.

Could eosjs team help to confirm this?

function lookupAsync(symbol, contract) {
    assert(symbol, 'required symbol');

```
assert(contract, 'required contract');

if (contract === 'eosio') {
  contract = 'eosio.token';
}

var extendedAsset = symbol + '@' + contract;

if (cache[extendedAsset] != null) {
  return Promise.resolve(cache[extendedAsset]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

eosjs team confirmed, question could be closed now.

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/issues/152